# How to create outlook contact conflict

Tags: microsoft-outlook

We have a program which automatically exports contacts from our software to outlook. Normally it works fine. But sometimes the user gets contact conflicts in outlook and this causes some errors. So to fix that, I need to create such a conflict. But I couldn't do that. I tried a lot of things:

- Copy them
- Copy to other list and back
- Change something - removed from network - changed something again and add network
- Copy in list while import from our program
- Changed contact an readd them
- Change one filed and copy them

I wasn't able to do a conflict item.
The conflict item should have this symbol:
[image: conflict symbol]

Does anyone know how to create such a conflict manually, that we can test our program and fix this error.

Comment: Do you mean that you encountered a contact conflict issue along with that specific symbol and you want to reproduce the same issue? So, what's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). I have kept using Outlook desktop client for a long time but have not seen this button yet. Please try to provide me with more related information for further research.

Comment: Yes thats what I want. I have Office 2013. Microsoft describes the Conflicts here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/about-conflict-resolution-for-custom-item-types . For my case I need to create such a conflict of a contact to reproduce the error. So as long as I don't have a contact conflict I can't reproduce and fix that problem.

Comment: Still could not reproduce the conflict issue in outlook desktop client. Found a similar issue as you, maybe you could check if the workarounds in this thread could help solve your issue.  https://www.tenforums.com/microsoft-office-365/152521-microsoft-outlook-creates-many-conflicting-contact-records.html